# Number of times Tags used in post which were commented by user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a simple Blog App and I am trying to implement a feature.

In which, If a user commented on a post with `post tags` - `tag1, tag2`.
And I will retrieve the `Tags of which user commented on post` And i am trying to count `Number of times a user commented on a post with same tag`

Like I am trying to show :-

| Tag Name | Number of times used |
| --- | --- |
| tag1 | 16 Times |
| tag2 | 10 Times |
| tag3 | 8 Times |

This table is showing :- User commented on a post with the tag which was used in previous post.

**For Example :-**

A new user named "user_1" commented on a Post with tags `tag5`, `tag6`, `tag8` then A `query` will show that `user_1` has commented on post tags `1 times in tag5` , `1 time in tag6` and `1 time in tag8`.
And I will do the rest later.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeinKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tags = TaggableManager()

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    on_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def examplePage(request):
    query = Tag.objects.filter(blogpost__user=request.user)

    context = {'query': query}
    return render(request, 'examplePage.html', context)
```

This view is showing tags which are `used in post` which were commented by `request.user` like :-

```
tag1

tag2

tag2
```

But I have no idea, How can i annotate so it can show number of used tags which were on post commented by `request.user` like above table.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You.

**Note** :- I am using [Django-Taggit](https://pypi.org/project/django-taggit/) for `Tags` (`TaggableManager()` in BlogPost Model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `blogpost__user` would cause the tag to be filtered by (I assume) the author of the `BlogPost` instead of the commenter, so I think you would want to use `blogpost__comment__comment_by`?

With that you can annotate on the count of tags like this:

```
Tag.objects.filter(
    blogpost__comment__comment_by=request.user
).values(
    'name'
).annotate(
    times_used=Count('name')
)
```